# The steps to create an MVC web application

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web, e-commerce

I've read many tutorials about MVC method ... I am now about to start an e-commerce application with PHP... So I'm confused about from where to start.(What's the best directory hierarchy ,the files, the templates etc)

Knowing that I will create admin pages(in a subdirectory with MVC), and website pages ... all I want is to know how to organize all this.

I've already created PHP websites (I am good in PHP and OOP). But not with MVC.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Daniel A. White, there already exists a lot of PHP MVC frameworks. Have a look at:

- [DooPHP](http://doophp.com/) (Personally love this one!)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) (*updated for version 2*)
- [Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)

Comment: great list, but latest version of symfony (2.0) has a different url: [symfony.com](http://symfony.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different open source MVC frameworks for PHP such as CakePHP that should get you inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with a PHP framework like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) because it's already packaged with a simple, effective and easy-to-use MVC structure that'll get you up to stratch with the logic necessary to start programming this type of web app.  They also have a good user guide and support base - so help's never that far away if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thank you friend , I will look for this, But I just want to see how it works so I can build my own projects ... +1